# Composer returns ???? on CloudLinux ssh

Tags: ssh, cloud-hosting, composer-php

i've just installed composer through ssh on a CloudLinux server, and but it returns ??? when used. I installed it with

```
curl -s getcomposer.org/installer | php -d detect_unicode=Off
```

because my server apparently has `detect_unicode=On`

This is basicly how what it spits out when I type `php composer.phar`

```
????username@myserver.com [~/public_html/somefolder]
```

Did I forget something? Is this because of `detect_unicode`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of detect_unicode. You most likely don't need this setting on, and having it enabled messed up the phar handling.

Comment: I got it to work with `php -f composer.phar -d detect_unicode=off`

Comment: Yeah that's the other approach, but really I would recommend you just turn it off in your php.ini unless you know a good reason why you need it enabled.